# Javascript If statement to run function based on web page's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have my function executed when the width of my webpage is between 700px and 800px and the height is between 400px and 500px.

Here is my function:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        function checkWidth() {
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();

           if (windowWidth >= 700 && windowWidth <= 800 && windowHeight >= 400 && windowHeight >=500  ) { 

                 $('#text')
                .keyboard({ layout: 'qwerty' })
                .autocomplete({
                   source: availableTags
                })


               .addTyping();}        

                   }
        }

        // Execute on load
        checkWidth();
        // Bind event listener
        $(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

The function works but will not be executed once it is inside the if statement.

Comment: `windowHeight >=500` should be `windowHeight <=500`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lrwaukx/9/ example

Comment: I tried that and it only works in jsfiddle

Comment: probably you didn't add jquery ?

Comment: @FastSnail no i did <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> is in my header tags

Comment: then open the browser console and see the errors

Comment: @FastSnail thank you for all your help. I just got it to work.